# Error in make controller in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want learn larvel please help.

Using laravel version 5.0.16.

```
php artisan make:controller Admin\Controller --resource
```

It shows this error:

> [RuntimeException]   The "--resource" option does not exist.

What is the problem?

What is different between?

```
php artisan make:controller Admin\Controller --resource

php artisan make:controller Admin\Controller --plain

php artisan make:controller Admin\Controller
```

Comment: --resource doesn't exist in laravel 5.0

Comment: They have removed these option in Latest Laravel...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1st of all `--resource` does not exist in 5.0 and don't use / in controller name as you write above Admin/Controller make it as AdminController

**Short**

Now in Laravel 5.2 `make:controller` command creates plain controller, if you want to make resource controller you need to add --resource

**Resource Controller**

Resource controller gives four built-in methods of CRUD with routes as well, for example you run:

```
php artisan make:controller AdminController --resource
```

Then the routes can be registered as:

```
Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
```

It will give you four methods.

**Create Retrieve Update Delete**

Laravel resource routing assigns the typical "CRUD" routes to a controller with a single line of code.

**Plain Controller and without --plain.**

Before, Laravel 5.2 `--plain` was used to make a simple controller without builtin routes and methods. Now:

`php artisan make:controller AdminController`

Works the same as `--plain`.

**Reference:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers