# Resource Controller is not creating using artisan command line when using Nwidart module

Tags: php, laravel, module

I am using **Nwidart** in my laravel 5.6 application for modules system.

Outside module I can use this **command**:

```
php artisan make:model Product -mcr
```

This command create a model, resource controller, migration.
But when I want a model inside a module product, this command is not working. I write this command:

```
php artisan module:make-model Product -mcr
```

This command is giving this **error**-

> `The "-c" option does not exist.`

**what can I do for solving the problem?**

Comment: Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44404196/error-in-make-controller-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module:make-model` is a custom command provided by the package you're using. This command does not support the `-c` or `-r` options. It only supports the `-m` option to generate the migration, and a `--fillable` option to specify the fillable fields.

You can view the source of the command [here](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules/blob/4.0.0/src/Commands/ModelMakeCommand.php#L84-L90).

You'll need to run a separate command to generate the resource controller (`module:make-controller`).

Answer (score -1):

Try -a 
that will create model,ResourceController,Migrations, and Faker Factory too.